# What is the meaning of : "git+https://github.com/...."?

Tags: git, pip, https, github

What does url of the kind git+https mean?
I was installing an application and the command suggested was

```
"pip install -e git+https://github.com......"
```

Can someone please explain what it means.

Answer (score 14):

A URL like `git://github.com` will mean just the plain Git protocol. To clarify that it should use Git over HTTPS instead, the protocol is written `git+https`. Now, `git` itself does not need this, you can do just `git clone https://...`.

For other tools like `pip`, which can handle many protocols, `https://...` will indicate that it should do just a GET request for that URL, and `git://` would indicate that it should attempt to clone the repo with the plain Git protocol. `git+https` is used to indicate that it should clone the repo over HTTPS (just as `git+ssh` is used to indicate it should do so using SSH).

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the highest scored one.